# How to Destroy the call if the page is navigate?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I used `concatmap` to call the multiple requests. Following is my code

```
getGeneDetail() {
    const obs = from(this.genes);
    obs.pipe(
        concatMap(res => {
            const ep = this.callService.getAll(this.resource + '/' + res.name + '/status');
            return ep.pipe(map(r => {
                this.tableData[res.i]['x'] = r.gene[x].xpos;
            }));
        })
    ).subscribe();
}
```

And the `this.genes` contains the following data

```
    [
        {
            "name": "tim",
            "i": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "keratin",
            "i": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "isomerase",
            "i": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "evps",
            "i": 3
        },
        {
            "name": "ank1",
            "i": 4
        },
        {
            "name": "cdsn",
            "i": 5
        }
        .. ,more than 100 entities
```

Above code is working fine. But the problem if I navigates to another component the APIs are still calling.  So How to prevents the call if the page is navigates?

Comment: Another page you mean another component?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to navigate to another component.

Comment: Have you tried out ngOnDestroy() to destroy the component?

Comment: You have to unsubscribe the subscription in ngOnDestroy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the subscription, and then unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy. Otherwise, the subscription is still open, and will keep listening for changes

```
geneSub: Subscription;
getGeneDetail() {
    const obs = from(this.genes);
    this.geneSub = obs.pipe(
        concatMap(res => {
            const ep = this.callService.getAll(this.resource + '/' + res.name + '/status');
            return ep.pipe(map(r => {
                this.tableData[res.i]['x'] = r.gene[x].xpos;
            }));
        })
    ).subscribe();
}
ngOnDestroy(){
  if(this.geneSub) this.geneSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `takeUntil` in your pipe and create a 'reset' subject, which is completet in `ngOnDestroy`. See this article for details: https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/